# List/Report of all active Shared Links in the SharePoint Online tenant using PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, reports

Is there a way to generate a List/Report of all active Shared Links in the SharePoint Online tenant using Powershell?

I know that we can find that in "Security and Compliance" admin center audit logs. But this has only 3 month data and also the report has links which have been already deleted.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/use-sharing-auditing?view=o365-worldwide

I browsed everywhere and couldnt get any hint on how to proceed on this requirement